# vue-router access component data

Tags: javascript, vue-router

I am playing with an example given from vue-router documentation

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/foo">/foo</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>', data: {title: "Foo" }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>', data: {title: "Bar" }
```

Is it possible to access selected component data outside  anchor and update {{title}} header?

Full example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hga74mvy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've two possibilities. First one is to edit your parent data directly with `this.$parent.title`.
And the second way is to trigger an event `this.$parent.$emit('changeTitle', 'foo');`.

I think the last one is better, because the control of your state is always in your parent component.

```js
const Home = { 
  template: '<div>Home</div>', 
  data: {
    title: "Home"
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$parent.title = 'home'; // directly
  }
}
const Foo = { 
  template: '<div>Foo</div>', 
  data: {
    title: "Foo"
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$parent.$emit('changeTitle', 'foo'); // emit an event
  }
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { 
      path: '/', 
      component: Home 
    },
    { 
      path: '/foo', 
      component: Foo 
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Initial'
  },
  destroy() {
    this.$off('changeTitle');
  },
  created() {
    const _self = this;
    
    this.$on('changeTitle', function(newTitle) {
      _self.title = newTitle;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/foo">/foo</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Agree, second solutions is better.